# Magento 2 - No redirect to external payment provder

Tags: payment-gateway, magento2

Today I started working on a payment module for Magento 2. After a lot of try and errors I now have a payment module that can be configured and has restrictions.

Now, the next step would be to start a transaction request after placing the order. Within Magento 1 I would use getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() to return an url where the consumer would be redirected to.

When I try this with Magento 2 then the function is called but no redirect is done to the return url.

Does anyone know if this has changed within Magento 2 or what I'm doing wrong?

The function looks like:

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl(){


    return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('module/controller/method');

}
```

Comment: did you get another way to achive this?

Answer (score 4):

I've faced the same problem. After spending few days trying to debug getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl I've ended up doing the JavaScript ( kind of a hack ) version of redirection to payment gateway.
My guess is that Magento 2 simply didn't implement that yet in new checkout flow. I could be wrong, so try to check with Magento team if there's some designed way to do this. I simply didn't have more time to investigate.

What I've done, is to modify the payment method JavaScript renderer file, and implement my redirection there. Something like this:

```
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
    'mage/url',
],
function (
    $,
    Component,
    placeOrderAction,
    selectPaymentMethodAction,
    customer,
    checkoutData,
    additionalValidators,
    url) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'My_Module/payment/form-template'
        },

        placeOrder: function (data, event) {
            if (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            var self = this,
                placeOrder,
                emailValidationResult = customer.isLoggedIn(),
                loginFormSelector = 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]';
            if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                $(loginFormSelector).validation();
                emailValidationResult = Boolean($(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
            }
            if (emailValidationResult && this.validate() && additionalValidators.validate()) {
                this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false);
                placeOrder = placeOrderAction(this.getData(), false, this.messageContainer);

                $.when(placeOrder).fail(function () {
                    self.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(true);
                }).done(this.afterPlaceOrder.bind(this));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        selectPaymentMethod: function() {
            selectPaymentMethodAction(this.getData());
            checkoutData.setSelectedPaymentMethod(this.item.method);
            return true;
        },

        afterPlaceOrder: function () {
            window.location.replace(url.build('mymodule/standard/redirect/'));
        }
    });
}
);
```

afterPlaceOrder is the key modification here.
This will redirect to internal controller "mymodule/standard/redirect" right after Place order is clicked. Then use this controller to construct your external redirection, usually POST form submitted to payment gateway page.

The important here is to be aware that:

1. "mymodule/standard/redirect" will not receive any data from order page, so this approach is only possible if you can construct external redirection without data entered by customer during the checkout process.
2. "mymodule/standard/redirect" is basically hardcoded in JavaScript file, hence the "hack" reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look into this one as most payment methods don't require additional data within the checkout process. I will also contact Magento about this, just to make sure this is still the way to go with Magento 2.

Comment: I there a way to do it from model, like with getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()? I need to pass some params from order.

Comment: Can you please share how you redirected, because mine is not working at all

Comment: It's been four years so you might have forgotten everything about magento since then but I'll give it a try because I'm trying to use your method. Redirecting to my custom controller works great but how can I access the order details inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to analyse that i found for payment gateways was the paypal module.
If you see the

> ./vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-payment-method.js

You see what they do to redirect the user to a certain url. This url is provided by a config provider.

In my case, i developed a Redirect controller which redirects the user to the payment gateway.

The flow is:

Checkout -> (js) -> Redirect Controller -> (php) -> External Gateway -> Success/Cancel Controller -> (php) -> Checkout Onepage Success