# Magento 2 - Can't get order data in custom controller for payment gateway integration

Tags: magento, redirect, payment, magento2, gateway

I am developing a module for a payment gateway.

1. I created module skeleton using module creator provided [here](http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/payment-module).
2. I used redirection solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416686/magento-2-no-redirect-to-external-payment-provder/39190867#39190867).
3. I wrote custom controller where it is getting redirect.

Now in my custom controller I need to create data to post on the payment gateway and then will post that data to the payment gateway url.
Here I need order data which I and not getting in checkout session. I referred other extension they are using similar method but I am not getting any data.

```
protected function _getOrder()
{
    if (!$this->_order) {

        $incrementId = $this->_getCheckout()->getLastRealOrderId();
        var_dump($incrementId);
        $this->_orderFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory');
        $this->_order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    }
    return $this->_order;
}


protected function _getCheckout() {
    return $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
}
```

Comment: How did you solve your problem? I have this problem too, can you please explain about it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use following method of load order.

`$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);`

Comment: But I am not getting the OrderId also.